# Elixir Phoenix 1.6 - trying to pass token to browser, function nil.id/0 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels, ueberauth

I am working on a Phoenix 1.6 app.  I used Ueberauth for authenication via GitHub, which was working.  I set up a channel to post topics and comments, which authenticated users can do.  Next, I tried to add a user token for use in the channel.  I was following the instructions in the boilerplate code created using *mix phx.new.socket User*.  In the *user_socket.js* file, there are instructions for creating the token in a template, which worked.  The token is verified in *user_socket.ex* in the *connect* function. I created a new plug *put_user_token* in *router.ex* to add the token to the *conn*, which also worked. However, I had a problem with the logic in the plug.  This is my code:

```
  defp put_user_token(conn, _) do
    if conn.assigns.user do
      token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", conn.assigns.user.id)
      assign(conn, :user_token, token)
    else
      conn
    end
```

This works as long as I am logged in. The problem is when I log out and try to log back in.
The boilerplate code for the if statement in the plug is:

```
if current_user = conn.assigns[:current_user] do
```

My code differs because the current user is defined as *user*, with the value equal to the id of the user record in the database.
I think the problem is that when setting up Ueberauth, I created another plug *SetUser* that comes before the *put_user_token* plug.  This is the call function for SetUser:

```
 def call(conn, _opts) do
        user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)

        cond do
            user = user_id && Repo.get(User, user_id) ->
                assign(conn, :user, user)
            true ->
                assign(conn, :user, nil)
        end
    end
```

What seems to be happening is that, after I log out, the app redirects to the home page, which causes the plugs to execute, and the value of *conn.assigns.user* is set to *nil*.  Then the error occurs and I cant' log back in.

I need to come up with a way to have the *if* statement in the *put_user_token* plug be able to handle a *nil* value.  I tried *is_integer(conn.assigns.user)*, and a couple of other comparisons, but if a value of *nil* is present, the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question would be easier to answer if you could simplify it -- I suspect once you simplified the problem it would be clear to you where wires were getting crossed.  However, let me attempt a couple clarifications.

First, `if` statements are somewhat unidiomatic in Elixir -- you'll find that most often your execution flows can be defined without them and code is are usually easier to read when it doesn't rely on `if` statements.

Related, be very careful when using `if` to check the "truthiness" of a value.  This isn't just an Elixir thing, the behavior is a potential gotcha in any language.  I seem to remember PHP, for example, which evaluated an empty object as false in one version but true in another (!!).  In Elixir, `0` or an empty object both are "truthy", but not true... so all that to say that **it pays to be more explicit.**

For example, consider refactoring this code:

```
defp put_user_token(conn, _) do
  if conn.assigns.user do
    token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", conn.assigns.user.id)
    assign(conn, :user_token, token)
  else
    conn
  end
end
```

To something more explicit, perhaps:

```
defp put_user_token(conn, _) do
  case conn.assigns.user do
    nil -> conn
    user -> 
      token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", conn.assigns.user.id)
      assign(conn, :user_token, token)
  end
end
```

or consider pushing the pattern-matching all the way into the function signature, something like this (I'm not sure of the exact shape of the `conn`, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
defp put_user_token(%{assigns: %{user: nil}} = conn, _), do: conn
defp put_user_token(%{assigns: %{user: user}} = conn, _) do 
  token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", conn.assigns.user.id)
  assign(conn, :user_token, token)
end
```

You may find it more straight-forward to assign a simple boolean value like `:is_logged_in?` as the pivot point in your code because doing a bunch of checking for a value that MAYBE is a map/struct or MAYBE is nil can be confusing and is harder to read.

Lastly, double-check the other side of this code where you fetch the user data:

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
  case get_session(conn, :user_id) do
    nil -> conn
    user_id -> user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
      assign(conn, :user, user)
  end
end
```

or to be a bit strict and handle the possibility that the user ID in the session doesn't exist in the database, you could refactor this as a `with` statement something like:

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
  with user_id when !is_nil(user_id) <- get_session(conn, :user_id) 
   user when !is_nil(user) <- Repo.get(User, user_id)
      assign(conn, :user, user)
  else
    _ -> conn
  end
end
```

I think it would be easier to read if you moved the component steps into their own named private-functions which returned something more explicit than `nil`.

I would also take a moment to re-evaluate the flow here -- the app will not perform well if you need to hit the database for every request.  You should probably write the required user-data to the session only after successful login.

All code samples are untested.